# Finding CDF and PDF of random variable $Y=1-(1-X)^2$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

A random variable $X$ is drawn from a uniform distribution on interval $[0,1]$

$1)$ consider random variable $Y=1-(1-X)^2$, find it's probability distribution function $F_Y(y)$ and its probability density function $f_Y(y)$.

so far I have found (or tried) to get, could someone confirm?

$$F_Y(y)=1-\sqrt{1-y}, \ \ 0\leq y <1$$

and
$$f_Y(y)=F'_Y(y)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-y}}, \ \ 0\leq y <1$$

Comment: I think your question is from here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3634122/calculate-probability-distribution-function-and-probability-density-function-of, it's an application for the convergence of types theorem, you can find more details in Billingsley's book

Comment: that is my question and on that thread it is closed

Comment: Your question is related to the extremal distributions

Comment: looking at part 2) of my question, could you show how I could get $e(u)$ and $F_u(y)$?

Comment: I'm aware $F_u(y)=\frac{F_Y(u+y)-F_Y(u)}{1-F_Y(u)}$ would this equal $\frac{1-\sqrt{1-u-y} - 1-\sqrt{1-u}}{1-1+\sqrt{1-u}}$

Comment: Your computing is correct, the other one is also easy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106969/discussion-between-mq1998-and-kurt-w-x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is mostly okay.

1) Among other things, a *cummulative distribution function* must have an upper-infinite limit of one, so ensure that yours does too.  (ie: add what happens when $y\geq 1$.)

2) The probability density function is the *unsigned* derivative of the cummulative distribution function.   That doesn't change your answer, but should be noted for future reference.

---

Now, $X\sim\mathcal U[0..1]$ so $F_X(x)=x\mathbf 1_{0\leq x\lt 1}+\mathbf 1_{1\leq x}$ so...

$$\begin{align}F_Y(y)&=\mathsf P(1-(1-X)^2\leq y)\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(X\leq 1-(1-y)^{1/2})\\[1ex]&=F_X(1-(1-y)^{1/2})\\[1ex]&=(1-(1-y)^{1/2})\mathbf 1_{0\leq y\lt 1}+\mathbf 1_{1\leq y}\\[1ex]&=\begin{cases}1-\surd(1-y)&:& 0\leq y\lt 1\\1&:& 1\leq y\\0&:& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}\\[5ex]f_Y(y)&=\lvert {F_Y}'(y)\rvert\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{1}{2(1-y)^{1/2}}\mathbf 1_{0\leq y\lt 1}\end{align}$$

Comment: what do you mean by unsigned derivative? also is that supposed to be a +0.5 power instead of -0.5 for your $f_Y(y)$? Also to get end points zero and one for $Y$ do i sub in my end points of $X$ into the equation for $Y$? say for another case i had $Y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{X}}$ where $X$ is also uniform $[0.1]$ if i sub in the end points for $X$ into $Y$ i’d get the interval [1,+inf]?

Comment: lastly is the interval for pdf the same as cdf ?

Comment: An unsigned derivative is the absolute value of the derivative.  A pdf must be non-negative, and it is often useful to ensure this (such when applying a Jaccobian transformation).  If you have not encountered this topic, don't worry, just keep it in mind.

Comment: No, you should not just look at the end points.  Although *in this case* the local minima and maxima *do happen* to be located there, that will not always be so.  Over the domain $[0..1]$, the function $x\mapsto (1-(1-x)^2)$ is a bijection that has a local minima at $0$ and local maxima at $1$, and these have values $0$ and $1$.

Comment: The support for a distribution is the set of values of the random variable where the probability measure function (mass or density, as appropriate) is non-zero; that is, it is the set of realisable values for the random variable.  However, the cumulative distribution function is non-zero for *all* real values that are above the minimum of the support... on towards infinity.

Comment: so it doesn't matter the  interval in the random variable X is defined (in these cases $[0,1]$, but we instead just look for an interval where the CDF of Y is non zero?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107010/discussion-between-graham-kemp-and-mq1998).

Comment: **All** CDF are increasing functions.  They will be nonzero above the least value of the distributions support.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand with what interval is used for different CDF for different random variables.

Answer (score 1):

Your computing is correct.

Another way is to find the pdf first. Take $f \geq0.$ 
$$E[f(1-(1-X)^2)]=\int_{0}^1f(1-(1-x)^2)dx=\int_{0}^1\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-u}}f(u)du$$

$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-u}}1_{[0,1]}(u)$ finding the cumulative distribution function will be easy